# jquery.post() and php

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using $().post and php to change the contents of a <textarea>.

The script is succeeding - firebug clearly shows that the text in between the textarea tags has changed, and my little alert fires.

The user, however, doesn't see the changes. In Firefox the change doesn't occur at all, and in IE, the textarea updates up to 10 seconds late.

Here's the jquery I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pv_list li:first').addClass('hilite');
    $("input[name='db_entries']:first").attr('checked', 'checked');
    $("input[name='db_entries']").click(function () {
        $.post("changeEntry.php", {post: $(this).val()}, function(data) { 
            $("textarea").text(data);alert('done');
        });
        $('#pv_list li').removeClass('hilite');
        $(this).parent().addClass('hilite');
    });
});
```

At first I thought it was because the page didn't validate, but it validates xhtml transitional.

The thing that's really bugging me is I had it working earlier and can't figure out what I changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using [val()](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/val) to set the value of the textarea instead of text()?

```
$.post("changeEntry.php",{post: $(this).val()},
      function(data) {
          $("textarea").val(data);
          alert('done');
});
```

Comment: Well dang. I thought that was only for tags that actually have "input" in the tag name. 

Worked great. Thanks :)

Comment: Just think about how you'd do it with the normal DOM - it's still textarea.value - not textarea.nodeValue or textarea.data or anything else.

Answer (score 5):

Set `.val()` instead of `.text()`

Stackoverflow Archive:

- [Set Value of Textarea in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415602/set-value-of-textarea-in-jquery)
- [Insert text into textarea with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946534/insert-text-into-textarea-with-jquery)
- [How to retrieve the value of a textarea with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873536/how-to-retrieve-the-value-of-a-text-area-in-javascript)
- [Appending input-value to textarea-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913042/append-input-to-textarea-as-being-types-in-jquery)

Comment: Thanks guys. It's incredibly simple to do a site-search on google, so I'm trying to add an "archive" portion to any questions similar to past-subjects that google turns up.

Comment: Yeah, site:stackoverflow.com <search terms> is about a million times better than the built-in site search. I'm still waiting for them to wise up to this and integrate google search. Isn't there an API for it?

Comment: Paolo, yes, they could have it implemented rather easily - I actually set it up for a client today on their site. That being said, you can search all of the SO sites simultaneously from Firefox : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/879/make-the-search-box-return-results-from-all-stackoverflowian-sites/925#925

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to use the [load()](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load) function?

```
$("input[name='db_entries']").click(function () {
    $("#outputarea").load("?", {"paramName":this.value});
});
```

Comment: The whole purpose of the onclick handler is to set the contents of the textarea element, isn't it? And that's what load() does.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure, but one possibility is that you should do:

```
function(data){
  $("textarea").attr("value",data);
  alert('done');
}
```